# Use the inclusion-exclusion principle to determine

Tags: combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion, balls-in-bins

Use the inclusion-exclusion principle to determine :

(a) the number of ways there are to choose nineteen balls (identical apart from their colour) from a pile of red, blue, yellow and green balls if there have to be at most seven balls of each colour?

(b) the number of arrangements of length 9 of the numbers 1, 2, 3 and 4 (repetitions allowed) in which each number occurs at least once.

I have no idea how to approach part (a). For part (b), I think that the sets, say Ai, should be set up to be arrangements that do not have 1 or 2 or 3 or 4. Example : A1 be the set of length 9 of the numbers 2,3,4 and A2 be the set of length 9 of the numbers 1,3,4 and so on. Would this be correct and, if it is, how would I proceed with it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For (a), there are $\binom{19+4-1}{4-1}$ ways to choose without restrictions. If one of the $\binom41$ restrictions is violated, that leaves $\binom{19+4-1-8}{4-1}$ possibilities (since $8$ balls of the colour for which the restriction is violated are fixed), and if one of the $\binom42$ pairs of restrictions are violated, that leaves $\binom{19+4-1-8-8}{4-1}$ possibilities. Three or four restrictions can't be violated simultaneously. Thus inclusion-exclusion yields

$$
\binom{22}3-\binom41\binom{14}3+\binom42\binom63=204\;.
$$

For a general treatment, see [Balls In Bins [here: Colours] With Limited Capacity](http://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath337/kmath337.htm).

For (b), your approach is right. There are $n^9$ arrangements using at most $n$ digits, so inclusion-exclusion using the sets you defined yields

$$
4^9-\binom41\cdot3^9+\binom42\cdot2^9-\binom43\cdot1^9=186480\;.
$$

Answer (score 2):

$a)$

How many ways are there to select them so that two colors have more than $7$ balls? There are $\binom{4}{2}=6$ ways to choose the two colors. After that we can go ahead and take out $8$ balls of each of those colors. We must now select $19-16=3$ balls out of $4$ colors. By stars and bars there are $\binom{6}{3}=20$ ways to do this. So $6\cdot20=120$ ways in total.

How many ways are there to select them so that exactly one color has more than $7$ balls? First select the color in $4$ ways,let us assume it is red. After this take out $8$ balls of that color. We must now select $19-8=11$ balls out of $4$ colors, by stars and bars there are $\binom{14}{3}=364$ ways to do so. However out of those $364$ ways there are $20$ ways in which red and blue appear more than seven times, $20$ ways in which red and green appear more than $7$ times and $20$ ways in which red and yellow appear more than $7$ times. Therefore there are $364-3\cdot20=304$ ways in which only red is repeated. Therefore there are $4\cdot304=1216$  colorings in which exactly one color appears more than seven times.

Once we have this we can count the number of colorings in which no color apears more than $7$ times. This is because if we are allowed to color freely then by stars and bars there are $\binom{22}{3}=1540$ colorings. Therefore there are $1540-120-1216=204$ coloring in which no color appears more than $7$ times.

$b)$

This one is easier, we solve for an arbitrary length $n$ of words, where $n\geq 4$:

There are $1+1+1+1$ sequences with exactly one number.

How many sequences have exactly $2$ numbers? there are $6$ ways to choose the numbers and then $2^{n}-2$ sequences, so $6(2^n-2)$ total.

How many sequences have exactly $3$ numbers? There are $4$ ways to choose them. After this there are $3^n$ sequences with those $3$ numbers, out of these $3$ use exactly $1$ number and $3(2^n-2)$ use exactly $2$ numbers. Hence $3^n-3\cdot2^n-3$ use all of those three numbers. So $4(3^n-3\cdot2^n+3)$ total.

Therefore there are $4^n-4-6(2^n-2)-4(3^n-3\cdot2^n+3)$ words that use all four numbers.

Answer (score 2):

We outline a solution of (a).

We are not allowed to use more than $7$ blue balls, or more than $7$ yellow balls, and so on. Let us forget temporarily about that restriction.

If there is *no restriction*, then the problem is standard Stars and Bars. We want to find the number of solutions of $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4=19$ in non-negative integers. I will assume you know how to handle that.  Call this number $A$.

From the number $A$ obtained above, we must subtract the nuber of **bad** choices, where we have more than $7$ of some colour(s).

How many bad choices are there where we have more than $7$ red? Grab $8$ red.  Now we must choose $11$ balls, with colours chosen from our four colours. The number of ways to do this can be computed using Stars and Bars. Call this number $B$.  There are also $B$ ways to have more than $7$ yellow, and so on.

So is the number of bad choices equal to $4B$? Not quite. For it is possible to have, for example, more than $7$ red *and* more than $7$ yellow.  How many ways cn we have more than $7$ of each of these colours? Grab $8$ red and $8$ yellow. Now we must choose $3$ more balls. It is easy to count how many ways there are to do this. Call this number $C$. Similarly, there are $C$ ways to have more than $7$ red and more than $7$ blue, and so on, for a total of $\binom{4}{2}C$.

These $6C$ choices have been double-counted in the sum $B+B+B+B$. So the number of bad choices is $4B-6C$.

It follows that the number of ways to do the job is $A-4B+6C$.